# Пользовательский элемент управления для графического изменения текста C#

Tags: c#, usercontrol, textbox

Доброго всем дня!
Появилась необходимость создания собственного элемента управления. 
Суть: 
Есть код, который бьет текст на предложения. Вроде бы бьет правильно, по крайней мере проблем пока не встречал. Все полученные предложения должны размещаться в текстовом поле. Каждое предложение также должно быть обведено "рамкой"-линией (цвет для которой можно будет задавать в зависимости от типа и других характеристик предложения), но это еще не все. В случае если текст поделен на предложения неправильно, должна быть возможность перетащить правую границу любого предложения в определенное положение, после чего у всех экземпляров класса "предложение", которых это перетаскивание затронуло, должно соответственно измениться поле "текст". 
Вроде бы ясно, что копать надо в сторону usercontrol, но как именно рисовать рамки для предложений непонятно. Рисовать тупо поверх обычного текстового поля, на мой взгляд, не выход, т.к. при прокручивании скроллбара придется все перерисовывать.

Вопрос:
1.Какие будут идеи насчет реализации элемента управления или решения задачи в целом?
2. В какую сторону копать?

Благодарствую за внимание)
А если еще и мысль умную подкинете, так вообще тысячи спасибо!

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Вот над этим я еще думаю. Вообще сталкивался только с winForms, но судя по всему в wpf это реализовать будет гораздо проще.

Comment: "*Есть код, который бьет текст на предложения. Вроде бы бьет правильно, по крайней мере проблем пока не встречал.*" — Держите юнит-тест: `Слон сказал: "Привет. Добро пожаловать!" (Вредный был слон, хоть и... Приветливый. Приветливый — это фамилия у него такая была.) "Но..." — задумался тигр, — "я не хочу никого жаловать, "толстокожая скотина". Тигр (его звали Васильев А. П.) был воспитанным, поэтому съел слона и больше не задавался вопросами: жаловать? не жаловать? Такая вот Юж. Африка дикая. А ведь 1000 г. до н. э. шёл!`

Comment: Discord, без обид, но Ваш юнит тест никуда не годится. Мой код пройдет его на 100+. Код предназначен для более сложных текстов, содержащих сокращения (+ номенклатурные сокращения в технической документации) разных видов. Сюда кидать не стану -  самый короткий текст тупо не влезет. Единственный недостаток алгоритма: не распознает заголовки параграфов (без точки в конце) как отдельное предложение, а считает его началом следующего, если оно есть. Если следующего нет, то поставит в конце точку. Этот глюк сравнительно недавно заметил, но речь совсем не о нем и не алгоритме

Comment: @Discord великий и могучий во всей красе =) респект за кейс, аж самому интересно стало как это машине объяснить =)

Comment: речь о том как сделать чтобы текстбокс мог иметь коллекцию, каждый элемент которой еще и обвести рамкой можно было бы внутри этого бокса и вдруг чего не так - растянуть\сузить.

Comment: @sky49rus Если вы приглядитесь, то в тексте заведомо неразбираемое машиной разбиение предложений при условии, что она не понимает их смысл. Ну, кроме сокращений, схлопывания кавычек, вопросительных знаков без окончания предложения и прочих технических радостей русского языка. Так что мне действительно интересно, как ваш алгоритм справится с этим куском.

Comment: @Discord Извиняюсь за неточность. Не до конца изложил свою мысль. Тест никуда не годится, т.к. код предназначен для технической документации, а не художественной литературы. В ней не может быть прямой речи, вопросов и т. п. "Пройдет на 100+" касалось опять же мануалов. Более того код заточен под англоязычные тексты. Относительно вашего примера - прямую речь имеет смысл делить на отдельные предложения (с точки зрения языка). Скобки - отдельное предложение, прямую речь тоже вычислить возможно. А вот "Юж. Африка" и т .п. - это да, без словаря сокращений не обойтись

Comment: Но опять же.. вопрос то совсем не в этом.. В какую сторону копать, чтобы таки написать вышеописанный контрол?)

Comment: Возможно, вообще проще будет сделать версию на asp.net, но вопрос перетаскивания границы все равно остается открытым. Проблема даже не в самой рамке, а в том что текстовое поле должно вмещать коллекцию объектов и отображать их содержимое, которое можно обвести и при перетаскивании границы изменить. Это еще решаемо - через wpf или в крайнем случае проект asp.net, а вот перетаскивание границы даже не представляю как реализовать.

Comment: @sky49rus Я б копал в сторону WPF и смотрел, как там реализовано выделение, и как можно вычислить, где какой блок текста находится. Бонус в том, что в WPF выделение косячное (полупрозрачные прямоугольники поверх текста), и весь код доступен, а в WinForms выделение нормальное, но все контролы реализованы на уровне оси, а в .NET только тонкие обёртки. Для вашей задачи WPF со своими корявыми выделениями текста — то, что доктор прописал, уже половина задачи решена, осталось только передвижение границ сделать вашим способом. Правда есть риск, что код internal, но лучше так, чем совсем без кода.

Comment: @Discord: А в чём косячность? (Ну и прямоугольники по идее можно стилизовать, в отличие от.)

Comment: @VladD Есть четыре системных цвета: фон (белый), текст (чёрный), фон выделения (синий), текст выделения (белый). У полей ввода в WPF же выделение — это не стиль текста, а полупрозрачный прямоугольник цвета фона выделения, наложенный поверх невыделенного текста с прозрачностью 50%. В результате выделение выглядит не как белый на синем фоне, а как тёмно-синий на светло-синем. И нормальную расцветку невозможно получить в принципе: с каким цветом ни смешивай, светлый текст на тёмном фоне из тёмного текста на светлом фоне не получишь. В UWP сделано нормально, кстати.

Comment: @Discord: Хм, и правда. Не обращал раньше внимания. Не понимаю, почему они так сделали.